# Segmentation fault on a dynamic programming program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the problem of the cut-rod problem using recursion.
The problem is my program is giving a segmentation fault.
When running at gdb it gives me this error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555514f in cut_rod (
    array=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7fefd8>, 
    n=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7fefd0>) at cut_rod_rec.c:18
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>




typedef int32_t s32;


s32 max(s32 n1,s32 n2)
{
    return n1>n2?n1:n2;
}

s32 cut_rod(int *array,int *n)
{
    
    if(*n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    s32 q = INT_MIN;
    for(s32 i = 0;i<*n;i++)
    {
        q = max( q,array[i] + cut_rod(array,n-i )) ;
    }
    return q;
}

s32 main(void)
{
    s32 array[] = {1,5,8,9,10,17,17,20};
    s32 size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    fprintf(stdout,"Valor máximo obtido é %d\n",cut_rod(&array[0],&size));
}
```

Link to the problem:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cutting-a-rod-dp-13/

Comment: What have you learned while debugging?  Have you run your program with `valgrind` or compiled with the address sanitizer turned on?

Comment: cut_rod(array, n) always calls cut_rod(array, n)

Answer (score 2):

You have infinite recursion

```
s32 cut_rod(int* array, int* n)
{

    if (*n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    s32 q = INT_MIN;
    for (s32 i = 0; i < *n; i++)
    {
        q = max(q, array[i] + cut_rod(array, n - i)); <<<=======
    }
    return q;
}
```

when i is 0, first loop, you call `cut_rod(array, n)`

then when i is 0 you call `cut_rod(array, n)`

etc

forever

= stackoverflow

Comment: how could I fix this?

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to do so I dont know. Maybe start i at 1 but I am just guessing. I mean you know the algorithm you are implementing, so fix it